# Label Font and Text Fill disabled on Scene builder

Tags: css, javafx, scenebuilder

I'm fairly new to Scene Builder and JavaFXML. When I added a Label to my Anchor Pane, I couldn't change the Font of the Text and it's colour. Both the options have been greyed out and there's this CSS heading next to it.
How can I  not disable those options? This is the same case for the buttons too.

[image: Screenshot of disabled Font and TextFill on Scene Builder]

FXML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import com.jfoenix.controls.JFXButton?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Label?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.VBox?>


<VBox maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="672.0" prefWidth="176.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.141" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1">
   <children>
      <AnchorPane prefHeight="188.0" prefWidth="176.0" style="-fx-background-color: #1c94d900;">
         <children>
            <Label fx:id="StudentUSN" layoutX="15.0" layoutY="145.0" prefHeight="24.0" prefWidth="146.0" />
         </children>
      </AnchorPane>
      <VBox prefHeight="464.0" prefWidth="176.0">
         <children>
            <JFXButton fx:id="b1" prefHeight="44.0" prefWidth="176.0" style="-fx-background-color: #1156cf;" text="Attendance" />
            <JFXButton fx:id="b2" disable="true" prefHeight="44.0" prefWidth="176.0" style="-fx-background-color: #1156cf;" text="Clubs" />
            <JFXButton fx:id="b3" disable="true" prefHeight="48.0" prefWidth="176.0" style="-fx-background-color: #1156cf;" text="Results" />
            <JFXButton fx:id="b4" disable="true" prefHeight="48.0" prefWidth="176.0" style="-fx-background-color: #1156cf;" text="Feedback" />
         </children>
      </VBox>
   </children>
</VBox>
```

Comment: Have you set a custom style on the label? Please post the complete FXML.

Comment: No, I don't recall setting any custom style. @sillyfly

Comment: Are you sure this is the same file? For one - the label in your posted FXML has no text.  Additionally - does it happen if you don't include the `jfoenix` library?

Comment: Yes, this is the same file. I changed the text later on. And yes it does happen even if I've not included the jfoenix library.

Comment: Can you check if the FXML has a stylesheet applied? Go to Scene Builder Preview menu, select `Scene Style Sheets`, and see if under `Remove a Style Sheet` you find any css listed. If so, removing it should give you full control of your FXML styling.

Comment: It shows "None". So no stylesheets have been applied. @JoséPereda

Comment: When you create a new FXML file and add a `Label`, or open a different FXML one with labels, do you still have the blocked css settings? Or is it happening only with this particular FXML file? Which is your Scene Builder version?

Comment: The others don't have the blocked css settings. It's only with this particular FXML. My Scene Builder version is 8.4.1. @JoséPereda

Comment: Scene Builder has a preferences system, that stores preferences for the last FXML documents you use, including the applied css. What's your OS?

Comment: macOS @JoséPereda

Comment: On Mac, go to `/Users/<User>/Library/Preferences/` and open the file `com.oracle.javafx.plist` with Xcode. Now browse the file, go to `root/com/oracle/javafx/scenebuilder/app/preferences/SB_2.0/DOCUMENTS`. There you will find all the recent documents you have opened with Scene Builder. Look for the one with the css issues. Find the `sceneStyleSheets` property, and you should see a path for a css file. Just remove it, and close the file. Go back to Scene Builder an open the FXML file again. Does it still have the disabled fields?

Comment: No folder called "Library" is present under the <User>.

Comment: Yes, it may be hidden. Try Xcode directly?

Comment: The folder is hidden even on Xcode.

Comment: There are many ways to find it or make it visible. Like this [one](https://www.macworld.co.uk/how-to/mac-software/how-show-hidden-files-library-folder-mac-3520878/). TL;DR: Finder + `Shift-CMD-G` + `~/Library`.

Comment: When I opened the file properties in Xcode, the value of sceneStyleSheets was blank.

Comment: Check if there are other documents listed in preferences with the same name (they have a #_ prefix) that might have the css set. You can safely delete the entry for the document. Then open the file again with Scene Builder (the entry will be created again in preferences) and see if works now.

Comment: Nope, no luck on finding other documents with the same name.

Comment: Ok, so remove the entry for the document in the preferences file, and try again Scene Builder

Comment: Yeah!! It's back to normal. Thank you @JoséPereda.

Comment: Great, finally! I'll post it as an answer, in case others face the same issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Applying external CSS to FXML**

Given the simple test:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Label?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>

<AnchorPane id="AnchorPane" prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="600.0" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8">
   <children>
      <Label layoutX="448.0" layoutY="49.0" text="Label" />
   </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

and a separated css file:

```
.label {
    -fx-font-family: Roboto;
    -fx-text-fill: grey;
}
```

[image]

Without bundling a CSS file in the FXML file, you can add it to Scene Builder, so it will apply the styling to the preview.

This can be done from `Preview->Scene Style Sheets->Add a Style Sheet...`.

[image]

Once the style sheet is applied, some settings can be locked, meaning that the value is already set in the css file.

[image]

**Scene Builder preferences**

Scene Builder has an internal preferences system that keeps track of different settings for the recent FXML files used.

For each file it saves:

- name
- path
- X, Y, width and height
- divider positions, visible panes
- ...
- and the external style sheets files added to the FXML file.

This means that if you close Scene Builder, and you come back a few days later, when opening the same FXML file, all those preferences will be restored and applied.

In the case posted by the OP, for some unknown reasons, the css file was removed, but the lock was still applied.

So the quick fix in this case is just editing the preferences file, and removing the document entry. All its settings will be lost, but there is nothing really important there.

**Finding the preferences file**

On Mac, the file can be found here:

```
/Users/<user>/Library/Preferences/com.oracle.javafx.plist
```

and it can be edited with Xcode.

[image]

On Windows, the preferences can be found at this key in the registry:

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\JavaSoft\Prefs\com\oracle\javafx
```

and it can be edited with Regedit.

On Linux (possibly)

```
${user.home}/.java/.userPrefs/...
```

Answer (score 2):

Create a css file and add this style:

```
.label {}
```

Save your file and open SceneBuilder, Go to Preview->Scene Style Sheets->Add A Style Sheet...
Select your .css file and try...

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yIDc5.png)

Answer (score 1):

If you go to

```
'preview' -> 'Themes'
```

you've probably selected a non-fx theme like Gluon Mobile light. 
Just select Modena, and all your properties will be enabled again.

Select a theme that does not disable CSS manipulation:

[image]