# Why is Text and Font locked in Scene Builder for javaFX?

Tags: javafx, scenebuilder

I never used JavaFX before, I am trying to learn it by following tutorials online, This is locked for me in Scene Builder, and I can't seem to find a proper solution for the problem.

This happens when I try to change the color/font of a label:

[image: This is the screenshot taken from my problem]

Comment: Possible duplicated of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47050845/label-font-and-text-fill-disabled-on-scene-builder/47104659#47104659)

Comment: I looked at that first @Jose Pereda It didn't solve my problem.

Comment: A CSS file is applied to your FXML file. Find it first and either remove it or modify the label style there

Comment: Don't see any css files located where the fxml file is saved, any specific location I should look for?

Comment: It is either added inside the FXML file (`stylesheets`) or externally via Preview->Add style sheet, as explained in the question linked above

Comment: By any chance are you applying the Gluon theme or using ant of the Gluon controls? Then you have the Gluon style sheet applied

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Label Font and Text Fill disabled on Scene builder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47050845/label-font-and-text-fill-disabled-on-scene-builder)

Comment: I seemed to have applied the Gluon Theme, removing it resolved the problem, was unaware that it would restrict the access of customizing text. thanks for the help!

Comment: It is not a “restriction”, if you are styling via css, you shouldn’t style again in your FXML file, so Scene Builder prevents you from it.